# How to display error message of Rest API?

Tags: c#, node.js, api, xamarin

I am currently developing a mobile app that uses a Rest API.

I have almost finished but I wanted to know how to display the error message (in DisplayAlert) programmed in the API that is returned when an error in the app.

I don't know how to do. Kindly guide me in this regard?

**EDIT** : Here is the code I use, for registration for example

```cs
private async void BtnApply_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ApiService apiService = new ApiService();
   bool response = await apiService.RegisterUser(EntName.Text, EntFirstName.Text, PickerGender.Items[PickerGender.SelectedIndex], EntPhone.Text, EntEmail.Text, SelectCity.SelectedItem.ToString(), EntPassword.Text);

   if (!response)
   {
      await DisplayAlert("Oops", "Une erreur s'est produite", "OK");
   }
   else
   {
      await DisplayAlert("Bravo", "Vous êtes maintenant un membre de l'appli !", "Super");
      await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new PopupCGU());
      await Navigation.PushAsync(new LoginPage());
   }
}
```

and the code of API Service :

```cs
public async Task<bool> RegisterUser(string lastname, string firstname, string sexe, string phone, string email, string city, string password)
{
   var httpClient = new HttpClient();
   var registerModel = new RegisterModel()
   {
      lastname = lastname,
      firstname = firstname,
      sexe = sexe,
      phone = phone,
      email = email,
      city = city,
      password = password
    };

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(registerModel);
    var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("URL", content);
    return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
}
```

Comment: use a DisplayAlert?  Your question is very vague so it's hard to give an answer

Comment: Yes it is. It's to display the error in the DisplayAlert

Comment: if you already know how to use DisplayAlert, then what specifically do you need help with?  Your question does not contain any useful information we could use to help you.

Comment: Do you need to know how to parse the API response? Or...?

Comment: @Jason I need help on how to display the API error message in the DisplayAlert

Comment: `DisplayAlert("Error",errMessage,"OK");`

Comment: ok but what should i do first?  a try catch?

Comment: you have not posted ANY code so we have NO IDEA how your REST API works or what mechanism it uses for error handling.

Comment: @Jason Sorry for yesterday, I was tired and I had forgot the code. So now I have update my message with the code :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try catch is not necessary because the application will not crash if  HTTP request failed. , just show the corresponding error message with StatusCode from rest api.

```
 Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format(Constants.TodoItemsUrl, string.Empty));
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TodoItem>>(content);
        }
        else
        {

            string errorMessage = null;
            switch (response.StatusCode)
            {
                case HttpStatusCode.Created:
                    {
                        errorMessage = "the request resulted in a new resource being created before the response was sent.";
                        break;
                    }
                case HttpStatusCode.BadRequest:
                    {
                        errorMessage = "the request is not understood by the server.";
                        break;
                    }
                case HttpStatusCode.Conflict:
                    {
                        errorMessage = " the request could not be carried out because of a conflict on the server.";
                        break;
                    }

                default:
                    {
                        errorMessage = "Default error";
                        break;
                    }
            }

            DisplayAlert("Error", errorMessage, "OK");
        }
```

---

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/web-services/rest#creating-data .

#### Update

```
     Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format(Constants.TodoItemsUrl, string.Empty));
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            TodoItem Item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TodoItem>(content);

            if(Item.result == true)
            {
                DisplayAlert("", "Successful", "OK");
            }
            else
            {
                DisplayAlert("Error", Item.errorMessage, "OK");
            }             
        }
```

Comment: Hello @ColeX - MSFT,
Thank you for your reply.
But for example, what do I do if I have several possible error messages for a task?
For example, for the registration I can have 15 different messages for an oversight or an entry error.

Comment: You could return the error messages in response directly , check my update .